# Where to put custom and third-party classes in a CakePHP project?

Tags: php, cakephp

I've just started working on an existing CakePHP project.  I will be developing a class that does some operations on an Excel spreadsheet.  Like a PEAR object, the class will be called by Cake components, but in and of itself it will not call any Cake components.  Where is the best place to put the class file in the project hierarchy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In one of the vendors folders (/app/vendors, or /vendors if you want to use your class in multiple applications), see also: http://book.cakephp.org/view/538/Loading-Vendor-Files

Comment: Cake 2.0 url: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#loading-vendor-files